# Derive roots with multiple therms

Tags: derivatives

I have this function:
$f(x)=\frac {x×\sqrt {-3x+9}}{2}$
Now I also tried to write it differently:
$f(x)=\frac {x×(-3x+9)^\frac {1}{2}}{2}$
However I have no idea how I could derive it. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you know the chain rule?

Comment: And the product rule?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: By the chain rule and the product rule we get
$$f'(x)=\frac{1}{2}\left((-3x+9)^{1/2}+x\frac{1}{2}(-3x+9)^{-1/2}(-3)\right)$$